# Laravel Json array data display blade file

Tags: laravel

I have three column with different data. every column store data in json format, but now i want to display them, but its not working: Bellow my code:

Response:

```
"[{"type":"pllet-a","price_km":50,"size":28000,},{"type":"pellet-b","price_km":40,"size":20000,}]"
```

I want to display only value Example (50 km) in foreach loop. What is the way to fix it into laravel blade file. I have tired json_decode but not working.

Comment: fyi, that's invalid JSON

Comment: Post the code you already have, along with any error you get